# Looking for a CMS to embed news articles into my Bootstrap website

Tags: html, content-management-system, embed

So I have been working on a news page for website using Bootstrap Studio (I am new to all of this, only have been using html, css, and a tiny bit of js), and I was just creating individual html pages for each article and manually adding them to a list of articles on a news page. I started looking into it and found the a CMS may be a perfect solution so that I dont need to manually create these pages and can just "create" them in a CMS and somehow import them to my website.

So here is my goal, I want to just have some "recent News" blocks display the most recent articles image and title, as well a dedicated "news" page that displays every article. Also, I want the articles to be displayed on my website, as opposed to linking to an external page.

Is this at all possible, and if so, where would be the best place to start.

I appreciate any and all advice.

Answer (score 0):

If your website is primarily a blogging styled website, my recommendation would be to convert your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files over to WordPress.

There is a free template called HTML5Blank which allows you to completely style your site with your own HTML and CSS.

[Here is a great tutorial.](https://youtu.be/bvAKY8sQpRA)

Comment: I am looking more for some kind of widget i guess in order to just embed recent articles on the home page of my website.

Comment: Right on. WordPress is built primarily with PHP. If you know a bit of PHP, you should (in theory) be able to pull the blog posts from your WordPress account and implement them on your own website and style out the blog how you wish.

This has actually been a topic here on site, check it out:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001229/pulling-posts-from-another-wordpress-site